# Existence of extreme points

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a reflexive, smooth but not strictly convex Banach space. Since $X$ is not strictly convex, it is clear that there exists a maximal face $C \subseteq S_X$ which is not a singleton.

I do not understand the following assertion: "Since $X$ is reflexive, there exists an extreme point $e \in$ ext$(C) \subseteq $ ext$(B_X)$".

Why can we assert that the singleton $\{e\}$ is a face of $C$ using the reflexivity of $X$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X$ is a reflexive Banach space, by Dieudonne's theorem, its closed unit ball is weakly compact. Besides, since $C$ is a maximal face of $S_X$, there exists $x^* \in S_{X^*}$ such that
$$ C = (x^*)^{-1}(\{1\}) \cap B_X, $$

Moreover, $(x^*)^{-1}(\{1\})$ is also a weakly compact subset since $x^*$ is weakly continuous, then, $C$ is weakly compact.

Now, $C$ is under the hypotheses of Krein-Milman theorem, which guaranteed the existence of extreme points for $C$.